# What knowledge was Jim Taggart trying to evade when he hit his wife?

Tags: atlas-shrugged, ayn-rand

> [Cheryl Taggart] moved her hands in groping gestures, half-waving it away, half-trying to grasp it; when she answered, her words did not quite name it, but they were the only words she can find: "You... you're a killer... for the sake of killing..." **It was too close to the unnamed**; shaking with terror, he swung out blindly and struck her in the face.

Jim Taggart's evil is, of course, on full display here - not only in his disgraceful physical and emotional abuse of his wife, but also in the violence and destructiveness that's central to his philosophy of life. Of course, later he *does* realize the truth about himself when he realizes - to his horror - that he wanted Dr. Ferris to kill John Galt (even though it would mean his own death).

Is this what he's trying to evade here - the fact that he doesn't *want* to live, the fact that he claims to want to live while seeking to destroy everything that actually makes life possible? Or is "the unnamed" something else here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you got it. Jim was terrified to face the truth about himself: that he is a destroyer and that he is evil. It's too ghastly a fact for him to acknowledge. Cheryl touched this nerve and it unraveled his facade and placed a crack in his veneer. That was intolerable for him. Ironically, in hitting her, he actually confirmed her discovery about him.

Consider the following quote from Owen Kellogg:

> "What makes you think that Ivy Starnes's purpose is life?"

This is a recurring theme in the book. The producers love and pursue LIFE, while the looters seem to want the opposite: DEATH.